# kohana 3.3 Routing in sub-categories

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I have this code with Route (using Kohana 3.3)

```
Route::set('admin', '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>))', array('directory' => '(admin)'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'main',
        'action' => 'index',
    ));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'main',
        'action' => 'index',
    ));
```

When I enter `www.my_site/admin`, it works correctly.

All users must be authenticated, so I redirect to the controller, where this happens.

```
public function before() {
    parent::before();
    Controller::redirect('admin/users/login'); ...
```

However, I get the following error:

> Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL admin/users/login was not found on this server.

How can I do a redirect/route to `www.my_site/admin/user/login`?

Comment: Do you have the `users` Controller with `action_login` method defined?

Comment: no, i have this structure
-Controller(folder)
--admin(folder)
---users(folder)
----login.php(controller) with code `code`class Controller_Admin_Users_Login ext....`code` where I will make processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned, does the controller and function exist?

Also it would be recommended to create the URL for redirecting via [Route](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Route)

```
$route = Route::get('admin')->uri(array(
    'controller' => '..',
    'action' => '..',
));
Controller::redirect($route);
```

Answer (score 0):

update***

**structure**
-Controller(folder)
--admin(folder)
---users(folder)
----login.php(controller)
`class Controller_Admin_Users_Login ext...`

**kingkero** replied helped me

```
$route = Route::get('admin')->uri(array(
            'directory' => 'admin',
            'controller' => 'users_login',
            'action' => 'index',
));

Controller::redirect($route);
```

but url have view **www.my_site/admin/users_login**

can we have view **www.my_site/admin/users/login**?

P.S. I'm sorry if I want too many:)

Comment: Is there a specific reason your controller is `users_login` instead of having a controller `users` with the action `login`?

Comment: This application architecture is built so that each "event" (login, registration, profile) should be done in a separate controller. And yes, I understand the difference in this case, I will have the first view of links. thanks for the help...